# NoSuchMethodError while running spark streaming

Tags: twitter, spark-streaming, fasterxml

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:                                                                                         
   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

I am creating a simple spark streaming application using twitter as source. But get stuck at this error. I am using spark 1.6.0 and scala 2.10.4.

Answer (score 1):

This exception usually indicates that you have multiple versions of the library available at run-time, and the chosen one isn't the one you're relying on. Perhaps two libraries compiled into an uber jar.

To avoid this, you can take precedence for your versions of the JAR by specifying them explicitly via `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath`. More can be read in [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)